# MySQL client goes down after using setPrimaryInstance() in InnoDB clustering, but the cluster remains up with all nodes functioning

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-innodb-cluster

So, I have a cluster of 3 nodes, each in a different data center located in the same city. My architecture is a single primary one where one node (let's call it Node 1) is primary and the other two are secondary nodes.

So, I noticed that the MySQL client is down. I tried to restart it but it failed. When I checked the logs, I saw an error that said: `InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11`.

At this point, trying to resolve the issue, the only thing that worked for me is when I used `lsof -i:3306` and killed the process that was associated with `mysqld`.

As I expected, killing the `mysqld` process forced my cluster to switch its primary node from Node 1 to Node 3. Then I used `mysqlsh` to manage my cluster and used the `setPrimaryInstance()` method to reswitch from Node 3 back to Node 1, as my primary node.

After doing so, the MySQL client in Node 1 stopped working again and it crashed and can't start again. I have to go through the same process (i.e. kill the process associated with it) for it to work again, which will again switch the primary node.

So, my question is: Is there any way to keep Node 1 as the primary node while MySQL client still works? And why does switching the primary instance make MySQL client go down anyway? I can't understand why it happens.

P.S. I also have mysql router installed on my system. And I am using MySQL version 8.0.25.

Answer (score 0):

The daemon is called `mysqld`.  This is normally "started" once after booting, probably automatically.

The commandline *client* is called `mysql`; this is not a 'service' and does not need `sudo`.

"Cluster" implies multiple servers.  That implies that you must connect to a specific machine (or through a proxy).  Running `mysql` without a `-h` asks to connect to the instance on the same machine, that is, through a "socket".

If that is not sufficient to figure out what to fix, then please list the machines involved, stating which MySQL component is on which server.  Include the client(s), such as `mysql`, MySQL Shell, and the "automatic scripts".

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I was already aware of that but unfortunately I did confuse the two in my question. Anyway, the MySQL client does not start when my InnoDB cluster is running and I'm wondering why. Is this normal for an InnoDB cluster?

Comment: I elaborated...

Comment: Thanks for your elaboration. I improved my post by taking your points into consideration and I also added more information on what is happening.